# GIMP and Matlab

Tags: images, matlab

I want to use Matlab to generate images (as Figures) and subsequently manipulate them. Can I use GIMP easily with Matlab?  For instance, can I call GIMP routines from Matlab?

Comment: It seems like you are not really looking for a software recommendation here as you've already decided which programs you are going to use. If that's the case, your question would be better suited for Stack Overflow (SO) since your question is asking about routines (aka code).

Comment: Regarding your question, it is possible to do that using a Python script since [Matlab support running a Python script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/450222-how-to-run-a-macro-from-excel-in-matlab) and [you can automate Gimp using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-command-line). I'd suggest trying to see if you can make it work and post a question on SO if you face any issues with some code and details on the issue you are facing.